# Listview handling clicks incorrectly

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview consisting of feeds which a user can like. However on clicking the like textview in one feed item is changing the status of likes in multiple feeds in the list view.
Here is a snippet of my code.

```
TextView likeStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_text);
    connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(view.getContext());
    likeStatusTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean isConnected = connectionDetector.isConnected();
            if(isConnected){
                 isLiked = false;
                //TODO update value of isLiked from table
                if(likeStatusTextView.getText().equals("Liked")){
                    isLiked = true;
                }
                if(!isLiked){
                    likeStatusTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(119,185,44));
                         likeIcon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_liked));
                    likeStatusTextView.setText("Liked");
                }
                else{
                    likeStatusTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(103,176,181));

                    likeStatusTextView.setText("Like");
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),rootView.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: what you want..what error y getting

Comment: When I click on like in a feed list item , the textviews in multiple list items get changed. I tried using notifyDataSetChanged() but to no use.

Answer (score 1):

```
connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(view.getContext());
likeStatusTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      TextView likeStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_text);
        boolean isConnected = connectionDetector.isConnected();
        if(isConnected){
             isLiked = false;
            //TODO update value of isLiked from table
            if(likeStatusTextView.getText().equals("Liked")){
                isLiked = true;
            }
            if(!isLiked){
                likeStatusTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(119,185,44));
                     likeIcon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_liked));
                likeStatusTextView.setText("Liked");
            }
            else{
                likeStatusTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(103,176,181));

                likeStatusTextView.setText("Like");
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),rootView.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: no check properly. do TextView likeStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_text); inside the onClick

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Anyways this doesn't work either as android listview items are recycled to save memory so the same textview is referenced for multiple list items I guess. Anyways I got it working. I stored the list of all like states in a Boolean arraylist and updated the textviews accordingly which worked.